# Is implementing a BFS with a stack instead of a queue the same as performing a DFS?

Tags: queue, stack, breadth-first-search

Typically, a BFS is implemented with a queue, so that you can traverse level by level. Would using a stack instead of a queue cause the algorithm to become just a DFS without recursion?

I'm thinking that it would, as the LIFO structure of the stack would mean, each time you pop an element and push it's children onto the stack, the next element to be popped will be it's child rather than it's neighbor.

Anyways, just wanted to see if others agree

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is essentially what happens when replacing the queue with a stack. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode) also agrees:

> If  is a tree, replacing the queue of the breadth-first search algorithm with a stack will yield a depth-first search algorithm.

The above quoted article has some more details on the differences, and provides pseudo code:

> ```
> procedure DFS_iterative(G, v) is
>     let S be a stack
>     S.push(v)
>     while S is not empty do
>         v = S.pop()
>         if v is not labeled as discovered then
>             label v as discovered
>             for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do 
>                 S.push(w)
> ```

Comment: Any feedback on this answer?